# $A,B,C,D,E,F,X,X,X,Y,Y$ be arranged in a row so that every $Y$ Lies between to $X$'s (not necessarily adjacent)

Tags: combinatorics

> In how many ways can the following 11 letters: $A,B,C,D,E,F,X,X,X,Y,Y$  be arranged in a row so that every $Y$ lies between two $X$ (not necessarily adjacent)?

The "not necessarily adjacent" thing it getting everything messed up to me. I dont know how do I solve this. Any hint will be helpful.

Comment: Pick the distance between the outermost two $X$'s.  Pick where the left-most $X$ is.  Given that information so far, choose how to place the inner-most $X$ and $Y$'s inbetween the outermost $X$'s.  Finally, finish off by placing the rest of the letters.

Comment: @JMoravitz Trying... But 3 X's are making things complicated to me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First step:

Don't distinguish between $X$ and $Y$. So how many different ways are there to to arrange $A,B,C,D,E,F,Z,Z,Z,Z,Z$?
The answer is 
$$\frac{11!}{1!\cdot 1!\cdot 1!\cdot 1!\cdot 1!\cdot 1!\cdot 5!}=6\cdot 7 \cdots 11$$

Second step:

For each of such arrangements there is always the same number of ways to replace the $Z$ by $X$ and $Y$ so that the constraints are satisfied. This does not depend how the $A,B,C,D,E,F,Z$ are placed in the string.
The most left $Z$ and the most right $Z$ cant be replaced by an $Y$ so must replaced by $X$. The remaining three inner $Z$ must be replaced by $X,Y,Y$. These are 
$$\frac{3!}{1!\cdot 2!}=3$$
 possibilities.

So the result is

$$(6\cdot 7 \cdots 11)\cdot 3$$

Comment: Great :D Thanks... But you didn't need to add that XXY can give 3 ways :P :P

Comment: @RezwanArefin I want to emphasize the similarity of step 1 and step 2.

Answer (score 3):

Approach via cases and multiplication principle:

- Pick the distance between the outermost two $X$'s.  Call this distance $k$.  $k$ will range from $4$ to $10$

Given a specific $k$, continue with the following via multiplication principle:

- Pick where the left-most $X$ is.
- Pick location of the inner-most $X$.
- Pick location of the $Y$'s
- Pick what letter appears in every remaining unused location.

---

We get as a result $\sum\limits_{k=4}^{10} (11-k)(k-1)\binom{k-2}{2}6!=997920$, agreeing with the given books answer.

---

Shorter solution which matches the books given answer format:

- Pick the locations occupied by $A,B,C,D,E,F$  This can be accomplished in $\binom{11}{6}\binom{11}{5}$ ways.
- Pick which letter specifically occupies each of those chosen spaces.  This can be accomplished in $6!$ ways
- Now, the leftmost and right-most unused spaces must be occupied by $X$'s.  Pick among the three remaining unused spaces which is occupied by an $X$.  This can be done in $3$ ways.

This gives the answer of $\binom{11}{5}6!\cdot 3$

Comment: I think the might be some simpler solution ... This problem is from a book ... The book provides only Answers... the answer to this was $3 \cdot \binom{11}{5} \cdot 6!$

Answer (score 1):

**AS OF NOW, THIS GIVES THE WRONG RESULT**

The way I would do it would be to create the basic structure:

$$XYYX$$

and then count the number of ways to distribute the other letters over that, given that any of the remaining letters can be anywhere in that expression. To the left of everything, between $XY$, $YY$, $YX$, or to the right of everything. You must also be careful with counting distributions that give the same configuration. For example, adding an $X$ to the left and then an $X$ to the right gives the same as adding an $X$ to the right and then an $X$ to the left.

There are $5\cdot6\cdot7\cdot8\cdot9\cdot10$ ways of distributing all other $6$ letters, except for the third $X$. For example, $FAXBCYYDXE$ is such an arrangement. For the third $X$ how many places are there? Note that while you technically have $11$ spots, placing the third $X$ immediately to the left of immediately to the right of an $X$ bears no difference. To make it explicit, I will index the $Xs$: you have $FAX_1BCYYDX_2E$ and want to place $X_3$. Doing $FAX_1X_3BCYYDX_2E$ or $FAX_3X_1BCYYDX_2E$ is the exact same thing as far as letters are concerned. Thus there are $9$ different places. This makes $5\cdot6\cdot7\cdot8\cdot9\cdot10\cdot9$ arrangements.

Comment: The 3rd X doesn't count at all?

Comment: So what is the result?

Comment: I can find the the ways of inserting the other charecters. But dont know how to cope with the 3rd X

Comment: Although this is technically correct, I feel as though it will be too confusing and difficult to account for overcounting.  If you break it apart even further as I suggest in my comment above, no such issue occurs.

Comment: @RezwanArefin I added a spoiler that shows how to account for the 3rd X.

Comment: @JMoravitz your approach has more simpler steps indeed. Now a problem arises: the solution given by the OP does not match this one, but I cannot find the error.

Comment: I think you have counted those combination where 2 'Y's are adjacent ... But they dont need to be adjacent

Comment: @RezwanArefin that was just because of the example I gave; the number of arrangements I counted does not need the $YY$ to be adjacent.

Comment: @RSerrao solution from OP does match my answer, but is given in a different format.

Comment: @JMoravitz I have seen it; does not match mine. Unfortunately I cannot find what is wrong with mine

Comment: Your answer in nice.... Maybe you are missing very little thing. This is closed to the right answer

Answer (score 1):

Divide your letters into two sets, the specials $S=\{X,X,X,Y,Y\}$ and the rest $R=\{A,B,C,D,E,F\}$.

Because we're not allowing the $Y$s to be outside the $X$s, there are $3$ arrangements for the specials : $XYYXX,  XYXYX,  XXYYX$

The rest have $6!=720$ arrangements.

Finally we need to weave the two sets back together. We can put them together in $\binom {5+6}5 = 462$ ways (eg. like $rrssrssrrrs$ for $r\in R, s\in S$)

This gives $3\cdot720\cdot462 = 997920$ options.